Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "c" is null error for mule flow
I try to run my mule apps under runtime 4.6.7 from anypoint studio IDE.
It failed by starting and throws the error (Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "c" is null)for my flow "imp_get:\rest\v1\service-orders(serviceOrderId)"
any hints or suggestion how to debug such error will be more than welcome
please see error and flow as below
error
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'imp_get:\rest\v1\service-orders\(serviceOrderId)': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6f0369bd' of type [org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.ErrorHandlerFactoryBean_ByteBuddy_org_mule_runtime_core_internal_exception_ErrorHandler] while setting bean property 'exceptionListener'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6f0369bd': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "c" is null
    at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.lambda$build$1(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:531) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.6.7.jar:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:224) ~[mule-core-4.6.7.jar:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1102) ~[mule-core-4.6.7.jar:?]
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1020) ~[mule-core-4.6.7.jar:?]

the flow
<flow name="imp_get:\rest\v1\service-orders\(serviceOrderId)" doc:id="025691fe-eb05-4cc5-be58-c5d31b028c62" >
            <ee:transform doc:name="init vars" doc:id="6979887a-1fae-4af8-b102-9e3d78e2dd80">
                <ee:message />
                <ee:variables>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="operationType"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    "api-rest"]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="operationStatus"><![CDATA["success"]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="businessEntityDetails"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    {
        serviceOrderId: attributes.uriParams.serviceOrderId
    }]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="originalAttributes"><![CDATA[attributes]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="noDataFound"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    false]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="businessEntityId" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    attributes.uriParams.serviceOrderId]]></ee:set-variable>
                </ee:variables>
            </ee:transform>
            <ee:transform doc:name="request serice order" doc:id="9f14f0b2-21ee-43c4-b902-69e286c27e3a" >
                <ee:message >
                </ee:message>
                <ee:variables >
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="serviceOrderId" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    import * from dw::core::URL
    output application/json
    ---
    encodeURI(attributes.uriParams.serviceOrderId)]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="queryParam" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    var expandSpecificData = (attributes.queryParams.expandSpecificData default "false") == "true"
    var expandTextData = (attributes.queryParams.expandTextData default "false") == "true"
    var expandPartnerData = (attributes.queryParams.expandPartnerData default "false") == "true"
    ---
    {
        expandSpecificData: expandSpecificData,
        expandTextData: expandTextData,
        expandPartnerData: expandPartnerData
    }]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="requestHeader" ><![CDATA[output application/java
    ---
    {
        x_conversation_id: attributes.headers.'X-Conversation-Id'
    }]]></ee:set-variable>
                </ee:variables>
            </ee:transform>
            <try doc:name="Try" doc:id="4d92f031-cc98-4a38-9349-4a3ae98372f7" >
                <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" doc:id="e0b3e101-97ae-45f9-980d-2bba12a19ef3" config-ref="HTTP_get_codex-closing-sys" path="${codex-closing-sys.path-serviceOrderId}" />
                <error-handler >
                    <on-error-continue enableNotifications="true" logException="true" doc:name="On Error Continue" doc:id="5718ba83-be9f-4f0c-9716-7dd552ca2ebd" >
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="a61dae32-5918-4efc-b175-0bc79def06a3" >
                            <ee:message >
                                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    error
    //error.muleMessage.typedValue]]></ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                            <ee:variables >
                                <ee:set-variable variableName="operationStatus" ><![CDATA["error"]]></ee:set-variable>
                                <ee:set-variable variableName="httpStatus" ><![CDATA[404]]></ee:set-variable>
                                <ee:set-variable variableName="responseError" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    {
        "type": "CLOSING-EXP:NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The serviceOrder is not found"
    }]]></ee:set-variable>
                            </ee:variables>
                        </ee:transform>
                    </on-error-continue>
                </error-handler>
            </try>
            <choice doc:name="Choice" doc:id="0e92c648-0251-462e-9f4b-fc1a6ccf422d" >
                <when expression="#[!isEmpty(payload.data)]">
                    <ee:transform doc:name="responseCodex" doc:id="d2044aea-b1fd-4a75-874c-4ed8c925d3d1" >
                        <ee:message >
                            <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    if(!isEmpty(payload.data.serviceOrderHeader)) 
        (payload.data)
    else 
        ({})
    ]]></ee:set-payload>
                        </ee:message>
                    </ee:transform>
                    <ee:transform doc:name="init companyCode" doc:id="8399099b-c8fd-43b0-a96a-19636de7be74">
                    <ee:message>
                    </ee:message>
                <ee:variables>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="companyCode"><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    payload.data.serviceOrderHeader.companyCode]]></ee:set-variable>
                </ee:variables>
                </ee:transform>
                    <flow-ref doc:name="getAuthorization" doc:id="2fa53737-4811-4470-b30f-edf7f1e5df8e" name="getAuthorization"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise >
                    <ee:transform doc:name="noDataFound" doc:id="1904f051-8456-4756-a63e-4b0df1d6eae9" >
                        <ee:message />
                        <ee:variables >
                            <ee:set-variable variableName="noDataFound" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    true]]></ee:set-variable>
                        </ee:variables>
                    </ee:transform>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <ee:transform doc:name="responseData" doc:id="ec3eb206-0634-4951-b8bf-1d3f1672ab1c" >
                <ee:message />
                <ee:variables >
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="responseError" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    if(vars.noDataFound)
    {
        "type": "ANALYTICS-EXP:NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The service order you are looking for does not exist."
    }
    else if (!vars.isAuthorized)
    {
        "type": "ANALYTICS-EXP:NOT_AUTHORIZED",
        "message": "Unauthorized" 
    }
    else if(!isEmpty(payload.error))
     {
        "type": "ANALYTICS-EXP:BAD_REQUEST",
        "message":  if(typeOf(payload.error) ~='Object')   payload.error.message else  payload.error  
    }
    
    else 
    {}]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="opretaionDetails" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    if(!vars.noDataFound  and vars.isAuthorized )
      vars.operationDetails ++ { "httpStatus":200}
    else 
     vars.operationDetails ++ { "httpStatus":400}
     ]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="operationStatus" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    if(!vars.noDataFound and vars.isAuthorized )
       "success"
    else 
     "error"]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="responseData" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/json
    ---
    if(!vars.noDataFound  and vars.isAuthorized )
       vars.responseCodex
    else 
    {}
    ]]></ee:set-variable>
                    <ee:set-variable variableName="httpStatus" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
    output application/java
    ---
    if(!vars.noDataFound  and vars.isAuthorized )
    200
    else if (vars.httpStatus == 404)
    404
    else 
    400]]></ee:set-variable>
                </ee:variables>
            </ee:transform>
            <error-handler />
        </flow>


This is too broad. There is no way for people here to analyze this big chunk of code/flow and guess what is wrong at execution time. We can not reproduce this locally. You should add loggers or use a debugger (in Anypoint Studio or Anypoint Code Builder) and identify the exact line that is the source of the error and the values at that time. Then if you need help ask a new question providing a [mre].

if it fail to start in anypoint studio, how could  debug it? should be something related to configure ?

Fails at deployment, before starting the application? It could be anything. A configuration, a bug, a library. Try with a different version, maybe a newer one, like for example 4.8. If it is something inside the flow, try diving the flow into smaller private flows, to see if the error changes.

You said this happens when you run "mule apps under runtime 4.6.7". Does it mean that the issue is persistent for all applications, or just this one? Do it work with a different version? maybe 4.4 or 4.8?. What is the java version that you are using? 8 or 17

I found the reason , there is a extra    before, on GUI, it looks totally same, but when starting IDE, it failed with the wierd error Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "c" is null

Please write that as an answer instead of a comment.

I found the reason , there is a extra <error-handler /> before </flow>, On GUI, it looks totally same, but when starting IDE, it failed with the wired error saying Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "c" is null
